# If you had a t-shirt and on that t-shirt were printed some part of the civicrm codebase, what part would it be?

Tags: discussion

Serious question - the most popular answer will most likely make it onto one. Think hard, people, and feel free to make other thoughts and suggestions too...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trying to think of a clever play on the api syntax. Maybe

```
civicrm_api('Community', 'Create')
```

or else

```
civicrm_api('Scout', 'Fetch')
```

or maybe

```
civicrm_api('Warm_Beer', 'Get')
```

Comment: you meant to type civicrm_api3, didn't you ;)

Comment: civicrm_api3('Warm Beer', 'Get'); is my favorite!

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
  return self::_invoke($args);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException($e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try{
    $result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', $params);
  }
```

or maybe

```
civix generate:sandwich
```

Answer (score 0):

I would love to add some hooks reference like below -

```
function my_custom_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {

  // since the $form object was passed by reference, modifying it here will change it permanently

  $form->assign('intro_text', ts('hello world'));

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably wayyyyyy too late, but seems like something along these lines should be in the running:

civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php:    //  IF(civicrm_contribution.contribution_status_id = 1, total_amount, 0 ) as total_completed,

Answer (score 0):

```
// Fixme: dear god why? these come out in a format that is NOT the name of the fields.
  foreach ($nameFields as &$fix) {
    $fix = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($fix));
    if ($fix == 'prefix' || $fix == 'suffix') {
      // God, why god?
      $fix .= '_id';
    }
  }
```

Extract from https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/1e7702fee94c891c1c1b3ec4d43688991f96b6af/CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/Individual.php

Answer (score 0):

Personally, [CHILLING OUT AT THE CIVICRM_EMAIL TABLE](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-svn/blob/46df80d543362780c1661eb51aa32503e5ec53e5/drupal/modules/views/components/civicrm.core.inc#L929) might be the winner, or [logic may have eroded](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/dc1643f4670a5d14bb05cef5c39d96e889459d89/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php#L2506).

Comment: For more, https://gist.github.com/xurizaemon/571c495dbd7feaa129f0202e247d6634